# Input checkbox when i edit user no change

Tags: php, html

When i want to edit my user on inactive is it no working, but when i editing my users to inactive to active, it is working.

This is my PHP code: https://pastebin.com/iBaDxH2u

```
<input class="form-control" type="checkbox" name="actif" id="actif" value="<?php echo $userinfo['actif']; ?>" <?php if ($userinfo['actif'] == "1") { echo "checked"; } ?>>
<input type="hidden" name="actif" value="1" />
```

I dont solve the problem...

Thx

Comment: I don't see a form.

Comment: You have too many unclosed questions, IMHO.

Comment: The problem is with your html. You are using the name actif for both checkbox and the hidden field. In your php you will be getting any one of these values

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it has something to so with how checkboxes work. When you submit the form, if the checkbox is ticked then the page you submit the form to will receive `[actif] => on`. If you submit with the checkbox unticked then the page will not receive `[actif] => off`, it will receive an empty array `[]`. actif will not be set. Something like this might make it more obvious what is going on.

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['actif']) && $_GET['actif']=="on")
{
    echo ("The box was ticked");
    $ticked = 'checked';
}
    else
{
    echo ("The box was not ticked");
    $ticked = '';
}
echo ("<pre>");
print_r($_GET);
?>

<form>
    Actif <input type='checkbox' name='actif' id='actif' <?=$ticked?>>
    <button type='submit'>Click me</button>
</form>
```